# IP:Port mapping to a name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, virtualhost, webrick

I have deployed multiple rails apps on a rackspace server running WEBrick. Each of them runs on a different TCP port.

I can access port 3000 using `ptotem.com` (my domain name).
I can access other apps using `ptotem.com:3001`, `ptotem.com:3002`..., but I would like to access them using `appl_one.ptotem.com`, `app_two.ptotem.com`.

How could I do this with DNS?

Comment: do you have beside rails also apache running? do you have a webserver running on ptotem.com (on port 80 that is)? If so you have to dig into url rewriting or redirecting.

Comment: NO I do not have apache running.Only webrick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that, the DNS naming mechanism and the TCP/IP port mechanism are two seperate, unrelated entities, which exist on different layers of the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osi_model). If you think about it `appl_one.ptotem.com:3000`, `appl_one.ptotem.com:3001` and `appl_one.ptotem.com:3002` are still valid and would let you access your different apps.

You may be able to use [SRV records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) if both your name server and your application support them, but support for this is currently sparse and flakey at best.

The other thing you could look into for HTTP applications is running them on the same port and using virtual hosts with something like [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html).

When I *need* to do stuff like this I usually set my NIC's to have multiple IP's (or add more NIC's if they don't support this) and have my apps bind to a specific IP, but honestly, it's very rare that you actually *need* to do it, for the sake of typing `:port` on the end of your connect strings...

Comment: HI,Thanks for the answer.But I do not have apache running.Any solutions for webrick ?Sorry I am a bit newbie in servers so I maybe asking something very common !

Comment: I know next to nothing about webrick. Briefly looking around the internet, it doesn't look like there is much in the way of support for this, although webrick is (apparently) notoriously poorly documented. How much control do you have over the hosting server? If possible, you should try and move over to Apache, Nginx etc, especially if this is a production app... I have re-tagged the question to help you get attention from the right people.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you need to add a line to your /etc/hosts file.

for local host, testing, etc.

> 127.0.0.1 appname.com

or for private network

> 192.168.x.x appname.com

or public

> 210.32.197.4 appname.com